# Rails Database Query .order GREATEST ignore if NULL or empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to filter by a specific user's last activity in a discussion, so if a user made a post or a comment this discussion gets to be the first in their personal list.

Relations:

- a Discussion has_many posts.
- a Post has_many comments.
- a User has_many posts.
- a User has_many comments.
- a discussion has_many comments through posts.

My query pretty much works but only when both a post and comment from a user exist in a discussion.

How could I adjust my query to look either for the last_created post or last_created comment, meaning in my `.order` how can I ignore the `MAX(comments.created_at)` if this is empty and just
use `MAX(posts.created_at)`

```
@discussions = Discussion.
  joins(:posts,:comments).
  where(posts: {user: current_user}).
  where(comments: {user: current_user}).
  group('discussions.id').
  order('GREATEST(MAX(posts.created_at), MAX(comments.created_at)) DESC')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like this:

```
@discussions = Discussion
  .left_outer_joins(:posts)
  .left_outer_joins(:comments)
  .where("posts.user_id = :id OR comments.user_id = :id", id: current_user.id)
  .group('discussions.id')
  .order('GREATEST(MAX(posts.created_at), MAX(comments.created_at)) DESC')
```

You will need to use

- `left_outer_joins` otherwise the join would only find Discussion with both a matching post and a matching comment
- a `where` condition with `OR` because there might be only a post or comment from the current user in the row in after the join

Comment: Note that you actually don't need the COALESCE, because GREATEST will always prioritize NON NULL values.

Comment: @BenjaminCbr You are right. I missed that there must be at least one result otherwise the condition would have been false. I updated my answer to fix that issue.

Comment: This is not fully working, i can register the discussions in the users dash when i make a post in them, but if i create more discussions, and post in these, the discussion goes to the bottom of the list instead of to the top as intended, and no matter how many posts i make, the discussion will only go to the top if i make a comment in them, pretty weird behaviour.. , all i want is to have if any posts or comments are created in a discussion this discussion should go to the very top no matter what

Answer (score 0):

I think that two things are problematic in your query:

- the `joins` statement
- the `where` statements that use a reference to a table (users) that has not been join

Try doing changing the `joins` to a `left_joins` like so, and update your `where` condition as well so that it does not rely on joining the users table - which could cause other issues.

```
@discussions = Discussion.
  left_joins(:posts,:comments).
  where('? IN (posts.user_id, comments.user_id)', current_user.id)
  group('discussions.id').
  order('GREATEST(MAX(posts.created_at), MAX(comments.created_at)) DESC')
```

Indeed with a regular INNER JOIN (which is what the `joins` method do under the hood), you would only retrieve discussions for which there are both a comment and a post by your user, which is not what you want to do.

Comment: This is not fully working, i can register the discussions in the users dash when i make a post in them, but if i create more discussions, and post in these, the discussion goes to the bottom of the list instead of to the top as intended, and no matter how many posts i make, the discussion will only go to the top if i make a comment in them, pretty weird behaviour.. , all i want is to have if any posts or comments are created in a discussion this discussion should to the very top